# Jessie: How to log in to a Gmail account in Chromium 51

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, chromium, google-chrome

I am starting from a fresh NOOBS install on a Raspberry Pi 3B.

Once Raspbian is installed and working, I used:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I followed this procedure to ensure my clock is accurate as per the [National Bureau Of Standards'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology#Bureau_of_Standards) master clock (the atomic clock):

*[How do I set Raspbian to use the primary time server time.nist.gov?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/how-do-i-set-raspbian-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov)*

In Chrome://settings, select *About* and verify the version:

[image]

Back to settings, there is the normal opportunity to log in:

[image]

After the username/password, it triggers 2FA:

[image]

So far, so good.

But then it comes back with a screen that says,

> "UH, OH, SERVICE UNAVAILABLE - PLEASE TRY AGAIN LATER"

**The interesting part of this question is that out of a handful (9) of systems built just like this, from the same original NOOBS image, one of them logs in fine. Go figure.**

The others, all running the same version of Chrome, give this error message.

The workaround is to have to save the bookmarks as an HTML file and `scp` that file to the others so they at least have bookmarks for importing.

How do I log in to a Gmail account in Chromium 51 on Raspbian Jessie?

Comment: I don't know the answer but to cover our bases:

Happens regardless of whether in an incognito window?

Could you confirm that the clocks on all systems at hand are correct? (Run `date` to check, and run `sudo ntpdate -u time.windows.com` to correct if necessary).

Do you get the same problem attempting to log in with the Epiphany browser?

Your title says (October 2017) but from the screenshot you're running Raspbian 8 Jessie. Raspbian 9 Stretch came out in August and comes with Chromium 60 so version 51 is old by comparison. Have you compared the behavior on Stretch?

Comment: Haven't tried incognito.  As for times, I used this procedure:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68811/how-do-i-set-raspbian-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov to connect to the Natioinal Bureau of Standards Master Clock.  If 51 is old, then I wonder why it is not attempting to update itself...  I used the same original NOOBS for all of them.

Comment: Good to hear that your clocks are synchronized. Note that Chromium does not auto-update itself on Linux, but yes it should have gotten updated when you manually ran `sudo apt update...upgrade`. You could doubly check by running `sudo apt update; sudo apt install chromium-browser`. If it's still saying version 51 at after that then this would be odd even if you are running Raspbian 8 Jessie.

However, the Chromium version may be irrelevant if you are see the same login issues on Epiphany and Firefox. Would be good to get those datapoints for a frame of reference.

Comment: National Bureau Of Standards changed name in 1988. Why use the old name?

Comment: You'd have to ask them.  Source:  https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of what we learned via troubleshooting in the comments section:

Although Chrome has automatic updating on Windows and macOS, Chromium does not auto-update on Raspbian nor any flavor of Linux. To force an update of Chromium, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

It's hard to pinpoint exactly why logins were working fine on one system but not others, but running an old version of Chromium (April 2016 as turned out to be the case above) could naturally cause problems!